# python requests.get module is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program which checks the web url are working or not. It works fine if a site gives `404` but it does not work if the site gives `503 service unavailable` and gives exception.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib
import requests
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage

x = []
f = open('sites.txt', 'r')
dns = [line.strip() for line in f]
f.close()
for obj in dns:
    try:
        url = "https://" + obj
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print("Site is not reachable ", url)
            f = open("output.txt", "a")
            f.write(url + "\n")
            f.close()
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("Invalid URL", e)
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL as e:
        print("Invalid Line", e)
if os.stat('output.txt').st_size == 0:
    print('All sites are up. Exiting..')
    exit()
else:
    with open('output.txt', 'r') as fp:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = 'Alert!! following sites are not responding. Please check'
        msg['From'] = 'donotreply@admin.com'
        msg['To'] = 'niteshsinghal@admin.com'
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit()

    file = open("output.txt","r+")
    file.truncate(0)
    file.close()
```

when a site gives `503 service unavailable` then it goes to **exception** and not in **if** loop

**Output:**  Note: URLs are dummy in the result

```
Invalid URL HTTPSConnectionPool(host='operations.us-east-1.stage.admin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'operations.us-east-1.stage.admin.com' doesn't match either of 'admin.abc.us-east-1.stage.admin.com', 'www.admin.us-east-1.stage.admin.com'",),))
```

Please suggest what change need to be done so this will go into **if** condition only.

2. In addition, the script reads a blank line in the **sites.txt** in the end with no url and that gives `InvalidURL exception`. How can i fix that as well? 
   However, I've put that into an exception for now.

Comment: `try, catch and finally` maybe?

Comment: to handle empty line try this `dns = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]`

Comment: Thanks @SwetankPoddar I have added exception URL in my `output.txt` also which worked for me and I could get that URL in the email alerts.